# AWS: When setting IAM permissions for users/groups, do I need to give all permissions for services used in a cloud formations template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-service-catalog

I'm trying to set up a service catalog so that a test user can run a cloud formation stack. I gave the user/group permission for service catalog as well as s3. When I try and run the stack it gives me errors saying that I don't have enough permissions. The error can be seen in the image below. Do I need to give IAM permissions for ALL the services used in the CloudFormation template? I thought it wouldn't be necessary as it'll just run the template and make only what's issued in it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CloudFormation needs permission for what it does

We can use [AWS CloudFormation service role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-servicerole.html) -  to control the usage.

what this means is we have to give users the ability to create things with CloudFormation but at the same time prevent them from doing the same through the console or aws-cli.

Here is an example of how to achieve this - [CloudFormation Service Role Example](https://aws.nz/best-practice/cloudformation-service-roles/#:%7E:text=The%20most%20important%20permission%20it,to%20actually%20create%20the%20stack.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should setup a [AWS::ServiceCatalog::LaunchRoleConstraint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-servicecatalog-launchroleconstraint.html)
for your product.

The role will be assumed by your products to [launch it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-servicecatalog-launchroleconstraint.html). This way your uses don't need extra privilages, as every permission needed to launch your products will be provided by the role.